# I'm attempting to analyze a Scantron form and create a Key for a OMR project

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

[image: Scantron Key]
So I'm attempting to scan this form using OpenCV and essentially formulate a key for the questions that are marked. Now I've tried to go off some examples I've found online and I've converted it to a binary image, but I'm having issues detecting the marks for the questions. I made it somewhat through a tutorial I found online but they used a different formatted form and this form has a lot more material on it than the one displayed in the example and I could use some input from people more familiar with OpenCV. Help doesn't necessarily need to be improvements upon my code or even working code, it could be links and references to more helpful documentation, material or tutorials. 
[image: Binary of Key]

```
def analyzeKey(self):
    keypix = self.doc.getPagePixmap(0, alpha=False)
    keyim = self.pixel2np(keypix)
    cv2.imwrite("keyimage.jpg",keyim)
    key = cv2.imread("keyimage.jpg")

    grayscale = cv2.cvtColor(key, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayscale, (5, 5), 0)
    edged = cv2.Canny(blurred, 75, 200)
    cv2.imshow("Key", edged)


    cnts = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    docCnt = None

    # ensure that at least one contour was found
    if len(cnts) > 0:
        # sort the contours according to their size in
        # descending order
        cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)

        # loop over the sorted contours
        for c in cnts:
            # approximate the contour
            peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
    # if our approximated contour has four points,
            if len(approx) == 4:
                docCnt = approx
                break

    #originalkey = four_point_transform(key, docCnt.reshape(4, 2))
    #newkey = four_point_transform(grayscale, docCnt.reshape(4, 2))
    keyim[:,:,2] = 0
    cv2.imshow("Split",keyim)
    thresh = cv2.threshold(grayscale, 0,255,
                           cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    cv2.imshow("Otsu", thresh)
    cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
                            cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = cnts[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts[1]
    questionCnts = []

    for cntrs in cnts:
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
        ar = w / float(h)

        if w>= 20 and h>=20 and ar>=0.9 and ar<=1.1:
            questionCnts.append(c)

    cv2.imshow("cnts", questionCnts[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting the contours of the pencil marks, rather than thresholding, you could differentiate between the gray/black pencil marks and the orange text by using `cv2.inRange`.  You would choose a lower and upper bound for the allowed colors.  Here I simply choose black as the lower bound, and a gray color of (180,180,180) as the upper bound, and applied to the color image you gave.  Any pixels between those values are indicated in the output mask shown below.

```
img = cv2.imread('keyimage.jpg')
lower_bound = (0,0,0)
upper_bound = (180,180,180)
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower_bound, upper_bound)
plt.imshow(mask, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that makes it incredibly easier to analyze, I have a few questions: Once I reach that step is there a way I can grab which Question# is associated with the mark? plus my second question being how would i differentiate between the Questions and the ID Number, Form Number section that appears out to the right